# HTML Content type meta tag (utf8)

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, doctype

I have an html file encoded in ANSI. if I try to browse it, I get non-understandable chars like question marks.
I tried to put this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

but it didn't change any thing.

I converted the file into utf-8 and tried again and voila, it worked.

so I deleted the line above: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` and opened the file and it's displayed ok.

So, my question, is: What does this line of code mean?

Comment: What kind of characters? Which language?

Comment: If you make your file lie about its encoding, it's not going to work.

Comment: Arabic Language, I edited the question.

Comment: @SLaks so this tag has no use in life

Comment: @Ibrahim.I: You can only claim that your file is UTF-8 if it actually _is_ UTF8.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: Read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html It's a very concise and comprehensive text about encoding.

Comment: “ANSI” is Microsoft’s misnomer for a variety of encodings. So you should specify the actual encoding, preferably using its preferred MIME name, in the question. This is also the basic part of the solution: you should specify *that* encoding in a `meta` tag *and* make sure that there is no conflicting HTTP header in effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

- `http-equiv` attribute provides an HTTP header for the information/value of the content 
  attribute.
- The `content` attribute gives the value associated with the http-equiv or name attribute.
- The `charset` attribute specifies the character encoding for the HTML document.

Effectively, the above `<meta>` declaration will instruct the browser to have `text/html` type of document with the character set set to UTF-8.

Including the meta declaration won't make much of a difference if the `Content-Type` header is already served over HTTP. That is, the real HTTP header takes precedence over everything (UTF BOM is an exception) except user override. The `charset` attribute is just meant as a fallback and will only be used if the document decoding using the charset specified in the HTTP header fails.

Note that this is pointless if the file is not saved as UTF-8. The `charset` will be effective only if the file is saved as UTF-8. To save it as UTF-8, you can simply add a Byte Order Mark (BOM), at the very beginning of the file:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('yourFile.ext');
file_put_contents($your_file, "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$content);
```

See also:

- [Declaring character encodings in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software DeveloperMust Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)